# Using Hyphen in Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @dbinstance varchar(200)
DECLARE @dbname varchar(200)

SET @dbinstance = 'this-is-servername\databaseinstancename'
SET @dbname = 'databasename'

SET @query = 'select column1, column2 from +@dbinstance+'.'+@dbname+'


EXEC(@query)
```

I am getting the following Error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

If a servername has hyphen cant we use it in the variable? If so is there a work around for this as I'm not allowed to change the server name but have to use it in a variable.

Comment: SET @query = 'select column1, column2 from' +@dbinstance+'.'+@dbname REPLACE WITH THIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to quote your identifier as such:

```
[this-is-servername\databaseinstancename]
```

E.g.

```
SET @query = 'select column1, column2 from ['+@dbinstance+'].['+@dbname+']'
```

If your identifiers are likely to contain `]` you will also need to escape that as such:

```
REPLACE(@identifier, ']', ']]')
```

An alternative would be to use the built-in [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function as indicated by *Damien_The_Unbeliever* in the comments.

If your identifiers cannot be trusted (e.g. user input), you *MUST* escape them to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Or, you know, you could use the built in [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function that takes care of adding the `[]`s and the escaping, rather than doing it manually.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I was sure that existed. I was looking for it but couldn't find it, thanks!